# .net generate class from database table runtime

Tags: .net, database, orm, .net-2.0

I'm not finding an ORM that does this for .net 2.0 (i know it's old but some clients still use it)... anyway, I want to generate a class or properties from a sql query at runtime and use it. So, I use subsonic now and I generate the classes and then add them to my project..etc and this is great for objects I'm using all the time but sometimes for quick queries I want to be able to do something like this:

```
QueryClass result = ...(SELECT * FROM)
...SHOW(result.Column1, result.Column2)
```

So, above isn't real code but I want it to work like this. Anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: you can't do that with .net 2.0 easily. .net 3.5 you can a bit easier with anonymous types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use a Dictionary?

```
Dictionary<string, object> result = ...(SELECT * FROM)
...SHOW(result["Column1"], result["Column2"])
```

Comment: yes, I have done that in the past, I thought I'd try this out though. I don't know if it can be done.

Comment: As @Daniel A. White said, neither dynamic nor anonymous types exist in .NET 2.0. So, I don't think it's possible without creating a dedicated class.